# How to find out the key starting with same word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm having the following hash:

```
hash = {
  "Jason_1" => 2,
  "Jason_2" => 3,
  "Allison" => 1,
  "Jason_3" => 1,
  "Michelle" => 1
}
```

How can I obtain the values of the key starting with "Jason"? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a one liners:

```
# returns a hash with the elements
hash.select { |e| e.start_with? 'Jason' }

# if you want only keys
hash.select { |e| e.start_with? 'Jason' }.keys

# if you want only values
hash.select { |e| e.start_with? 'Jason' }.values
```

Comment: obtain *values* of hash where *key* starting with 'Jason'

Comment: If you read the question title, it's the *key* :) Thanks for the heads up. I'll update my answer for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
hash.map { |key, value| key =~ /\AJason/ && value }.compact
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with regexp:

```
hash.select { |x| x =~ /^Jason/ }.values
```

Comment: This will match `AllisonJason`.

Comment: Thank you  @ecmelkytz. i tried this too. its also worked with me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using scan and find_all method:

```
Hash[hash.find_all { |key, val| not key.scan(/^Jason/).empty? }]
```

If you are working in rails this should also work fine:

```
hash.slice(*hash.keys.grep(/^Jason/))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a efficient way and in a single line:

```
 hash.select{|s,v| s =~ /^Jason_/}
```